# Can't make media keys work on i3 window manager

Tags: keyboard, i3-window-manager

I can't seem to get how to get media keys to work in i3 gaps on my Corsair K30.

I have added into config the following line but

```
bindsym XF86AudioNext       exec --no-startup-id playerctl next
bindsym XF86AudioPrev       exec --no-startup-id playerctl previous
bindsym XF86AudioPlay       exec --no-startup-id playerctl play
# bindsym XF86AudioStop     exec --no-startup-id playerctl pause
bindsym XF86AudioStop       exec --no-startup-id gnome-terminal
```

they work in a strange way. XF86AudioStop is completely ignored. I tried to test it and see if it will open gnome-terminal for example. Play works but pause doesn't. If I go to kde desktop all media keys and everything works without an issue. But in i3 I can't setup bindings neither for volume keys nor for media keys. Managed only to make next and previous buttons work with the config above.

Is there any kind of app that display which XF86 key is pressed or outputs it to terminal?

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the key corresponds to Stop and not e.g. XF86AudioPause?

Comment: I am not sure to which XF86 my media keys corresponding but I will try AudioPause, what about volume up and down? Is there any tool that can display which key is preased, or refference tabple that could match the output of screenkey to XF86?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have the correct keysym in the first place – for <kbd>⏸</kbd> it should be `XF86AudioPause`, for <kbd>▶ / ⏸</kbd> it might be `XF86AudioPlayPause`, or it might even be something completely different. (XF86AudioStop is the <kbd>■</kbd> "Stop" button.)

The keysyms for volume controls should be `XF86AudioRaiseVolume`, `XF86AudioLowerVolume`, and `XF86AudioMute`.

For checking X11 keysyms of a key there's `xev` and `xbindkeys --key`. (Note that they often won't see keypresses for already globally-bound keys, so don't use them in KDE.)

(Low-level evdev keycodes can be obtained with `evemu-record` or `libinput debug-events`; they're not the correct kind of code, but are useful to see whether the key is recognized at all by the kernel.)

Comment: How to reference their output to XF86 keys?

Comment: For `xev` or `xbindkeys --key`, the key name will literally show up in the output.

Comment: XF86AudioPlayPause doesn't work, I tried `xbindkeys --key` no result produced for any of the media keys, `xorg-xev` package reacts to multimedia key presses but it doesn't show which key is that. 
this is the output that I get:

MappingNotify event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    request MappingKeyboard, first_keycode 8, count 248

FocusOut event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x1800001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 35, synthetic NO, window 0x1800001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor.
I did that from i3 just to be clear.

Comment: They keys work in kde plasma not problem its just that I can't map the for same actions in i3. setxkbmap -query give same result in both desktops. I just don't know where to look further for information.

Comment: I have already bound media keys that is why they were not working with `xbindkeys -k`

Comment: Make sure you do that without any other key grabbers (xev cannot show keys grabbed by i3 or xbindkeys etc.) Try the low-level evemu-record just to see what evdev keycode is sent for that key