# Xev not detecting media keys

Tags: linux, keyboard, manjaro, i3-window-manager, corsair

My media keys are not detected on fresh Manjaro i3 edition, they worked normally on KDE edition before. When i try to use xev to check key codes nothing is happening when i try to use sound, mute and media keys, other keys are detected normally.

My keyboard is Corsair K-70 Lux. I tried use my second Corsair keyboard too and there is that same situation (before system change it was working too) with my 3rd Logitech keyboard media keys are working so i assuming some support for Corsair is not installed/started?

Any idea what is missing in system?

Comment: Hi @user3069488, I'm facing the same problem, I wanted to know if you were able to fix the problem. Can you please share your solution here?

Answer (score 2):

I found a [question with an accepted solution](https://superuser.com/questions/1407361/cant-make-media-keys-work-on-i3-window-manager/1407379) about getting the media keys on a **Corsair keyboard** to work with the **i3 window manager** on Linux. @user1686 mentioned that `xev` might not see global keys:

> xev cannot show keys grabbed by i3 or xbindkeys etc.

Other commands were listed to check keysyms:

> (Low-level evdev keycodes can be obtained with `evemu-record` or `libinput debug-events`; they're not the correct kind of code, but are useful to see whether the key is recognized at all by the kernel.)

Included in the answer was a list of some common keysyms and what they are usually assigned to:

> ...for pause it should be `XF86AudioPause`, for play/pause it might be `XF86AudioPlayPause`, [and] `XF86AudioStop` is the "Stop" button.
>
> The keysyms for volume controls should be `XF86AudioRaiseVolume`, `XF86AudioLowerVolume`, and `XF86AudioMute`.

Comment: Those commands still not recognize my media keys. I tested those keys names which You mentioned at the beggining, i started to look for keys when they didnt work. I think i just missing some driver in system and thats why those keys not working, but i do not know what. What is strange on second computer installed from same usb key media keys are working.